# bindservice vs startService for upload/download processes

Tags: android, multithreading, service, upload, download

I have a question about which type of service I should be using to run the uploading and downloading of data in my application.

Specifically it seems like a bound service (obtained by calling bindService()) is really more applicable since my background work is not running indefinitely and my understanding is that that is really the purpose of using startService/START_STICKY.

That said, I am running long uploads and downloads, and I do *not* want my service garbage collected mid-way through an upload/download regardless of what is going on with the application's UI (sent to background etc). As I understand it, if I have a bound service, it will be garbage collected as soon as the all the connections have been unbound. Does this mean my bound service would stop potentially midway through what it is doing?

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest looking into an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or making your `Service` [run in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground) with a `Notification`.

Comment: I actually cant use an IntentService due to potential concurrency issues. I am hoping to use this service for a couple of different things, not just uploading and downloading, and I will need some of these operations not to block eachother. Operations sent to IntentServices will always run serially as I understand it? If not, then that does seem like the right solution.

Comment: I have a mixed service for my app's background processes. It acts as an `IntentService` to schedule certain data-sync operations, but it can be bound to retrieve progress updates. I allow the service to continue downloading in the background, but I deliberately haven't made it persistent. It's my understanding that to prevent a service from being kicked out, you need to have a foreground notification up.

Comment: I was in the process of editing my comment to provide another option.  Making a service run in the foreground will signal to the system that garbage collecting your service could be disruptive to the user.  That could be a better option than an IntentService.

Comment: I notice that you say the background work is not happening indefinitely. Do you mind me asking what the frequency of uploading/downloading as well as load are? If they are infrequent short tasks, an AsyncTask may be better suited for your needs.

Comment: If you use bindService, your service will be destroyed when all the connections have been unbound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your `Service` run in the foreground by calling [`startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) will signal to the system that killing and/or garbage collecting your service will be disruptive to the user.  This will prevent the system from cleaning up your service unless it absolutely has to due to low system resources or low power.

To make a `Service` run in the foreground, you'll need to give it a `Notification`.  That can be done like so:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
builder.setContentTitle("Your notification text");
builder.setProgress(100, 0, true); /* 0 out of 100 progress to start */
builder.setAutoCancel(false);
builder.setOngoing(true);
Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

/* NOTIFICATION_ID can just be a static int to identify your service's notification */
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

This is a pretty basic example of using startForeground but should at least get you pointed in the right direction.  When your operation is finished, you can signal to the system that you're free to be collected by calling [`stopForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 0):

For this first let's review what's a service. A service according to Android documentation is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user.
When you use startService() you are launching a service that will run on the main thread and it's not connected to the Activity that launched it, therefore you cannot communicate with it.
When you use bindService() you are binding the service to the activity, and its alive while the activity is not killed (onDestroy method called or killed by the device to free memory).

My suggestion is that you use either an IntentService (search for a short tutorial) because in this case you can send a broadcast to the application, it runs in a different thread, and you can then receive a notification when the file finishes uploading.
Another approach you can use is to use a JobScheduler (came out on Android 21), in case you need to constantly be uploading/downloading files (kind of like what Evernote does syncing every N minutes on the background).

Hope it helps.